# How to select file using regex?

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
./Dockerfile
./Dockerfiles/Dockerfile
./Dockerfiles/prod/Dockerfile
./Dockerfiles/prod/Docke rfile



./Dockerfile/
./Dockerfiles/Dockerfile/
./Dockerfiles/prod/Dockerfile/
```

And I need to grab only

```
./Dockerfile
./Dockerfiles/Dockerfile
./Dockerfiles/prod/Dockerfile
```

I tried some like

```
^\.{1}\/{1}[A-Za-z0-9_-]*(\/{1}[A-Za-z0-9\/_-]*)

^\.{1}\/{1}[A-Za-z0-9\/_-]*
```

But that's not exactly what I need. **I use PCRE(PHP)flavor**

How can I do it using regex?

Comment: If all the lines show either a directory or a file, and any directory ends with `/`, then the easiest way is to check if a line *doesn't* end with `/`. `/^.*[^\/]$/gm`

Comment: Or `^\.\/.*$(?<!\/)`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6lIkkm/4).

Comment: @VLAZ thx for you answer. How to add excluding sting with space?

./Dockerfiles/Docke rfile

Comment: @IgorSamarskiy are you sure you want to exclude it? Files/directories with spaces are still valid identifiers. You can specify non-spaces by using `\S` instead of `.`

Comment: Well, actually, then you need `^\.\/\S*[^\s\/]$` - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6lIkkm/5). You also need to add the requirement to the question, please update it.

Comment: Have updated description. ^\.\/\S*[^\s\/]$ is working as expected. TNX @WiktorStribiżew. Please add it to an answer section and I will mark as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^\.\/\S*[^\s\/]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6lIkkm/5)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\.\/` - `./` string
- `\S*` - any zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `[^\s\/]` - any one char other than whitespace and `/`
- `$` - end of string.